# Проблемы с версткой слайдера в Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте.

С помощью плагина bxslider реализовал слайдер вида:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li style="background: url('files/slider/1.png') no-repeat center bottom;">
            <div class="bx-caption">
                <strong>Скидки</strong><br>
                круглый год 20%
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background: url('files/slider/2.png') no-repeat center bottom;">
            <div class="bx-caption">
                <strong>Бесплатная</strong><br>
                консультация
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background: url('files/slider/3.png') no-repeat center bottom;">
            <div class="bx-caption">
                <strong>Начало работ</strong><br>
                в течение 5 дней<br>
                с момента звонка
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background: url('files/slider/4.png') no-repeat center bottom;">
            <div class="bx-caption">
                <strong>Бесплатная</strong><br>
                доставка<br>
                в 15 км от КАД
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Вызов слайдера

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    pager: true,
    speed: 800,
    pause: 8000,
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
       $(".bx-caption").animate({opacity:0},300, function() {
           $(".bx-caption").css({top:"600px"});
       });
    },
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        $slideElement.find(".bx-caption").css({"opacity":"1"}).animate({top:"60px"},500);

    }
});
```

Во всех браузерах ок, кроме Firefox, в котором область вывода слайдера почему-то смещается вправо.

[Вот страница со слайдером.](http://yuginvestproekt.ru/z/service-page.html)

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил. Нужно было очистить поток для блока, содержащего логотип и меню. Почему-то нужно было это только Firefox.